# Memory Leaks in third party frameworks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sharekit

I am using sharekit in my application where while building and analyzing the application is showing some potential memory leaks and errors with sharekit.

I googled but could not get the accurate answers. I know how to resolve a few but i am sure whether i should do that or not.

Please suggest me what to do. I definitely don't want my first application to be rejected by apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple won't reject your application for having memory leaks (unless they are so catastrophically bad they cause near-instant crashes). There are plenty of leaking apps on the App Store.

Sharekit is an open source project, if you have fixes then I'm sure the project would be glad to receive them.